# In Microsoft Edge, sticky positioning doesn't work when combined with dir "rtl" attribute

Tags: css, microsoft-edge

I'm building a static site using gatsbyJS. i want to have a sticky sidebar. `position: sticky` works fine for Chrome and Firefox, but on Microsoft Edge 17 the sidebar is not displaying. This is because I have a `dir="rtl"` attr in my html tag. what do i need to do to have a sticky element with `rtl` dir in edge?

my sidebar component is nested in a layout component, which uses bootstrap to layout the page. I know about different possible polyfills, and I've also written some js to make it look ok with `position: fixed`.
but for what i see in [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) and other places it's supposed to be supported. So I'm wondering what am I doing wrong or is it an undetected bug?

here's my code.

sidebar.js:

```
const Sidebar ({ sidebarMenus }) => (
  <div id="sidebar" className="sidebar">
    <Menus menuList={sidebarMenus}/>
  </div>
)
```

sidebar.css:

```css
.sidebar {
  display: none;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
          position: sticky;
  top: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-right: 35px;
  max-width: 155px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 770px) {
  .sidebar {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

pageLayout.js:

```
const PageLayout = (props) => (
  <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col col-12 col-md-9">
        {props.children}
      </div>
      <div className="col col-0 col-md-3">
        <Sidebar page={props.page}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

Note: There's no css for the layout other than the bootstrap classes.

When loading the page in edge the sidebar just doesn't appear. It's visible in the DOM, and I can see it behaving as sticky in the dev tools, but it is not displaying. It's displaying only when i change my dir to the default `ltr`.
Any help on what is causing this will be greatly appreciated.

**update: apparently it's a known bug: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15754013/**

Comment: as i said the dir="rtl" was in my html tag. i can paste it as well if you like. i will check with a newer version of edge. but i don't understand your examples, they're showing position: fixed while i was talking about sticky.

Comment: I suggest you to make a test with the latest version of MS Edge. You are using Edge 17 is very old version. Where is dir="rtl" in your code. above code does not have that. I made a test with MS Edge 44 and these 2 examples are working fine with it. Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sticky_element

Comment: Please check with the updated example. It is also working fine with Edge.

Comment: I suggest you to post your work around as an answer for this question and mark it as an answer when ever it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: so in this example just add `dir="rtl"` to the html tag and run in edge and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bug  in MS Edge that prevents using the sticky position property while either of the html or body elements have a `dir="rtl"` attribute. Check the discussion at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15754013/.
As mentioned there, everything works fine if the `dir="rtl"` attr is set on a child element of the body.
So the workaround is quite simple: just set `dir="rtl"` to any container div (or other element) that's wrapping all the pages that needs to be in `rtl`.
I hope this helps someone.